TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" with Nodemon and TypeScript
1 package.json:
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js",`your text`
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node --esm src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "tsx": "^4.19.1",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cloudinary": "^2.5.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.21.1",
    "express-validator": "^7.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.7.1",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.7"
  }
}

2.tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ESNext", 
     "module": "ESNext",                              
     "rootDir": "./src",
     "moduleResolution": "Node",  
     "outDir": "./dist",
   },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node",}
}

Nodemon Configuration (if applicable):
{
  "watch": ["src"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "ts-node --esm src/index.ts"
}

Ensured all dependencies are correctly installed.
Tried running npm run dev and npx ts-node --esm src/index.ts directly.
Verified that my Node.js version is compatible (currently using [Your Node.js version]).
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_Eyour textXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for D:\project\src\index.ts
What might be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Can you share how the code looks like or a reproducible example?

It looks like something of the stack is unable to deal with TypeScript.
You may try running it manually, one by one to find what it causing error:
npm run ts-node -- --esm src/index.ts
npm run nodemon -- --exec ts-node --esm src/index.ts

But, ts-node is very slow (compared to other tools) and probably is not the best fit for new projects. Something like bun, Deno or nodejs + esbuild (or Vite) will do the trick without much easier setup.
With bun it is as easy as:
bun --watch src/index.ts

You may also wish to try tsx (as kind of replacement to ts-node, to stay with nodejs as a runtime), with tsx it is also as easy as
npm run tsx -- watch src/index.ts

